# "object tuple can't be used in 'await' expression" while using OpensearchVectorClient for llama-index

Tags: opensearch, llama-index, vectorstore

I'm trying to use OpensearchVectorClient() function in llama-index but I've run into a problem while calling OpenSearch: "object tuple can't be used in 'await' expression".
Here my code:

```
import boto3
from opensearchpy import RequestsHttpConnection, AWSV4SignerAuth
from llama_index.vector_stores.opensearch import OpensearchVectorClient

credentials = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id='aws_access_key_id',                                
aws_secret_access_key='aws_secret_access_key').get_credentials()
auth = AWSV4SignerAuth(credentials, 'eu-west-1', service="aoss")

client = OpensearchVectorClient(endpoint=[{"host": host, "port": 443}],
                                index=index_name,
                                dim=1536,
                                http_auth=auth,
                                embedding_field='embedding',  
                                text_field='content',
                                use_ssl=True,
                                verify_certs=True,
                                connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection)
```

Screenshot of the error: [Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKneJ.png)

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!